# Возможно ли такую логику сделать через LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Есть 3 массива. Требуется сравнить 
элементы массива1 и массива2, 
при равенстве элементов получить индекс элемента массива2, 
затем по этому индексу взять элемент из массива3, 
и записать его в список.

Можно ли это сделать через LINQ? Без LINQ получается вот что:

```
    int[] myArr1 = {3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; // тестируемый массив
    int[] myArr2 = {1,2,3,4};  // массив Ключей
    int[] myArr3 = {3,4,5,6};  // массив Значений
    var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>(myArr2.Length); // словарь

    // сравниваем первый и второй массивы и заполняем Словарь ключами и значениями 
    for (int i = 0; i < myArr1.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < myArr2.Length; j++)
        {
            if (myArr1[i] == myArr2[j])
            {
                if (!dict.ContainsKey(myArr3[j]))
                {
                    dict.Add(myArr3[j], 1);
                }

                else
                {
                    dict[myArr3[j]]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 2. Если верхний вариант не возможен, может ли упростить решение проблемы двумерный массив (если объединить в двумерный массивы  myArr2 и myArr3)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если это ваш реальный код, то вот решения с простым и понятным кодом.

Положим:

```
int[] tests = { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int[] keys = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] values = { 3, 4, 5, 6 };
```

Ваш код, переписанный простым способом, но с несколькими проходами по `tests`:

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<int, int>(keys.Length);
for (int ik = 0; ik < keys.Length; ik++)
    dict1[values[ik]] = tests.Count(t => t == keys[ik]);
```

Этот же код в виде LINQ:

```
var dict2 = keys
    .Select((k, i) => new { k, v = values[i] })
    .ToDictionary(a => a.v, a => tests.Count(t => t == a.k));
```

Если предположить существование словаря `keys`/`values`, который можно собрать следующим способом:

```
var kv = keys.Select((k, i) => new { k, v = values[i] }).ToDictionary(a => a.k, a => a.v);
```

...или банально построить его изначально:

```
var kv = new Dictionary<int, int> { { 1, 3 }, { 2, 4 }, { 3, 5 }, { 4, 6 } };
```

...то код становится ещё проще:

```
var dict3 = kv
    .ToDictionary(a => a.Value, a => tests.Count(t => t == a.Key));
```

**[update]**

Меня смутили ваши комментарии, и я написал глупость. На самом деле словарь не нужен. Всё вообще тривиально:

```
var dict4 = keys
    .Zip(values, (k, v) => new { k, v })
    .ToDictionary(a => a.v, a => tests.Count(t => t == a.k));
```

Comment: Ну, мне такой код и не написать. Посоветуйте книги, по каким научиться.

Comment: Чукча не читатель, чукча писатель. %) Если не считать запроса на слияние двух массивов в словарь, то я использовал самые азы LINQ, особенно в последней версии. @Zufir вот, напротив, использовал более хитрый приём — такой код с первого захода не каждый прочитает. В общем, не знаю, что посоветовать.

Comment: Обновил решение. Старый код можно выбросить. :)

Comment: Старик, ты гений!

Answer (score 2):

Что-нибудь такое?

```
        var xxx = from a1 in myArr1
                  let a2key=Array.IndexOf(myArr2,a1)
                  let a3 = a2key==-1?(int?)null:myArr3[a2key]
                  group a3 by a3 into cnt
                  where cnt.Key!=null
                  select new {key = (int)cnt.Key, qty = cnt.Count()};
```

Comment: Мне не нравится костыль для получения индекса, который портит красоту. Может, стоит переписать в виде цепочки методов, чтобы иметь доступ к индексу?

Comment: Спасибо, супер! По какой книге учились?